# JQuery Post from IFrame not working

Tags: jquery, post, iframe

```
<script>
function sendForm() {
  $.post("http://www.website.com/main/post.cfm",$("#testForm").serialize(),function(data,status){
    $("#result").html(data)
  });
  return false
}

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testForm").submit(sendForm);
});
</script>
```

and the following code for the IFrame:

```
<form id="testForm" method="post">
<label for="subscriberEmail">Enter your email</label> <input id="subscriberEmail" name="subscriberEmail" type="text" required="yes" validate="email" message="Please enter a valid email address" class="replaceText" value="Enter your email"/>
<input id="subscribe" type="image" src="signup.png"/>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Nothing is displayed in the div.result. However if I use the common action="http://www.website.com/main/post.cfm", it successfully returns the message reloading the whole IFrame.

Could there be an issue with $.post to a ColdFusion page?
Is there any work around or alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Check server's cross domain policy. For cross domain get method calls, use JSONP

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no, there could not be an issue $.post to a ColdFusion page".  The CFM code - running on the ColdFusion server - is completely unaware of how the request it receives was implemented: it seems no difference between someone typing a URL into the address bar, clicking a link, submitting a form or some clientside script triggering the request.  So this is not a ColdFusion issue.

You're a bit light on either troubleshooting (or the reporting thereof) here:
* are there any Javascript errors? (if so: what?)
* is the post() request actually being made, and if so what's the details of the HTTP request, and is it getting a response?

It might be worth temporarily converting your post() call to a vanilla ajax() call, so you can have an error handler specified, so you can react if there's an error (like write out the error to the console, etc).